# Libraries Component on Community Page is auto focused

Tags: community, community-builder, libraries

I have a community page which contains a [library](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_libraries_setup.htm&type=5) community component, added from the community builder.

[image]

This component, when loaded, displays a folder. On page load, this folder is auto focused, making the page scroll down automatically, ultra annoying.

I am trying to find a way to prevent my page from being scrolled down on load.

Maybe a way to solve this is to prevent the component from being focused or by focusing something else on the community page, I really don't know.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you raised a support case with Salesforce about this behaviour?

Comment: Good point, I will try it. Thanks.